# smooth bitmap loading in gridview

Tags: android, image, caching, grid

i am using the image cache/loader/resizer found in BitmapFun.zip in http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

I am allocating 0.15f of total memory and using it in a gridview of 3 columns (image size of about 80dp by 80p) ... it runs fine and loads the images(found locally on my phone) but there's a delay before images appear.... (it takes some time to load/resize the images) which is sometimes annoying.. why isn't it as smooth as stock gallery for example which seems to appear almost instantly?

Comment: Check out Picasso: http://square.github.io/picasso/.

Comment: it's a nice library but still not as smooth as stock gallery... have a delay before displaying the images.. sometimes the delay is really big.. how does stock gallery manage such smooth display? does it have bigger priority than other apps?

Comment: I agree with the delay. I switched to using Ion which seems faster & also very easy to integrate. https://github.com/koush/ion

Comment: it seems that this is for http download only? i am displaying only local image files

Comment: Aside from http, you can pass content URIs. i.e. content://path

Comment: I just tested Ion, but it's also slow